# what is the alternative of 'urlpatterns += ' in django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In older version of Django, there was an option to setup urls this way

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    )
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    ...
    )
```

In docs for [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) its not seen, while till 1.7 there existed.

How do I split up a big url pattern list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django 1.8, `urlpatterns` should be a list of `url()` instances. Splitting the urlpatterns should be easy, because you are simply adding python lists.

```
mypatterns = [
    url(...),
    url(...),
]

extrapatterns = [
    url(...),
    url(...),
]

# define urlpatterns by adding two lists
urlpatterns = mypatterns + extrapatterns

# extend the urlpatterns
urlpatterns += [
    url(...),
    url(...),
]
```